# Xaml C# replacing images from an array of images

Tags: c#, xaml

Ik in windows forms I could add images in resources and then change the images as users click on an event handler not sure whats changed in Xaml but I cant figure it out.

```
private void guessClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wrongGuesses++;
    hangmanPicture.Image = hangmanImage[wrongGuesses];
}
```

if I just put `hangmanPicture = hangmanImage[wrongGuesses];`
I get can not convert. I don't understand why its trying to convert anything.

Comment: What is the `Type` of `hangmanPicture.Image` ? And what is the `Type` of  `hangmanImage[]` ? Can you show exactly what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your *hangmanImage* array is an array of `ImageSource` or `BitmapImage`, you can use it like this:

```
private void guessClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wrongGuesses++;
    hangmanPicture.Source = hangmanImage[wrongGuesses];
}
```

Otherwise, you have to convert anything in *hangmanImage* into `ImageSource` or `BitmapImage`.
If it's `Bitmap` you can use below converter before that code:

```
    public static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using(var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage;
            bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
            memory.Position = 0;
            bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

So, then it will be like this:

```
hangmanPicture.Source = ConvertToBitmapImageFromBitmap(hangmanImage[wrongGuesses]);
```

Comment: I know windows forms is getting old but things were so easy and now its just a headache takes the joy out of coding. Ive always used C# and forms to code my apps and when I heard that xaml was like html I jumped on it because I develop websites but I don't even want to code Microsoft apps after this.

Comment: It's OK. but when you start to use benefits of WPF, you'll like it. Anyway, in your code, you just have to change the `.Image` into `.Source` in the last line.

Comment: Okay so here is my array of images  Bitmap [] hangmanImage = { Properties.Resources.step1,....} and when I try to change image to source I get can convert and convert method doesn't have anything for converting images. Thank You so Much